# error trying to use _tstoi

Tags: c++, cstring

I try to convert the last char of a `CString` to `int` using `CString::GetAt()` and `_tstoi()` but the compiler returns me `error C2065: '_tstoi' : undeclared identifier`. I guess i have to include a header file, i've tried `#include "tchar.h"` with no succes.

```
    CString str = "something2";
    int index = 0;

    if (!str.IsEmpty())
    {
        index = _tstoi((char*)str.GetAt(str.GetLength() - 1));
    }
```

EDIT: I use VC++ 6.0

Comment: Well, to start with the `GetAt` function returns a _single `char`_ while `_tstoi` wants a C-style string (i.e. a `char *`).

Comment: To convert a single char `c` to an integer, you can simply use `c - '0'`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg did that, but the compiler never got there because it can't identify `_tstoi`. I've tried using `atoi`, but at run it askes me for `atox.c` file.

Comment: Oh, and i forgot to say that i use VC++ 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function under VC6 is _ttoi rather than _tstoi (still included in the header 'tchar.h')

Comment: using `_ttoi` throws me an `unhandled exception` at runtime, asking me for the path to `atox.c`

Comment: That's because of what Joachim mentioned earlier, 'GetAt' returns a char and you're casting it to a char*. Use `char c = str.GetAt(str.GetLength() - 1);` `index = _ttoi(&c);`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code you should correct it like CString str = "something2";